# IIS7.5 MVC\Forms sub-application inheritance downloads instead of executing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, inheritance, web-config, iis-7.5, nopcommerce

Hey everyone and thanks for taking the time to help.
I am stuck on this problem. I have an asp.MVC application and my client want to use nopCommerce for the shopping cart. I made a test MVC application and got the sub-application working great on a simple demo. The nopCommerce virtual directory is registered as an application in IIS and it runs fine in the demo. However when I try integrating the steps into my application I get a run-time compilation error:

CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Combres' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
   Line 56:                 <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
   Line 57:                 <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
   Line 58:                 <add namespace="Combres" /> <-----Error Line
   Line 59:             </namespaces>
   Line 60:         </pages>
```

The sub-application (nopCommerce) does not use Combres so I thought it was an inheritance issue so I did the location trick in the parent Web.Config file:

```
   <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
       <system.web>
           ...
       </system.web>
   </location>
```

This got rid of the compilation error, but now there is no compilation of the file, the .aspx files just download to my computer instead of being executed. The main MVC application still runs great, I only get this downloading issue when I try to run the nopCommerce application.  I am completely stumped, I am kind-of an IIS noob and am having to learn quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K found the answer to this. My companies platform, we use ASP.net MVC, was turning all requests with file.* into download requests. So what I wrote was working great, it was doing what is was supposed to...I just didn't know.